# c# Como validar contraseña con almenos 1 mayuscula, 1 minuscula y 1 digito en MVC

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, mvc

tengo que hacer un registro de usuario en el cual me piden una validacion para la clave.

Tiene que tener almenos 1 mayuscula, 1 minuscula y 1 digito, como podria validar esto?

Yo he estado validando de la siguiente forma, con data annotation, pero a la hora de hacer esta validacion me entrevere.

Estoy utilizando asp.net MVC!

**Aca valido con dataannotation**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Esta es mi controladora**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

desde ya muchas gracias, si me pueden dar una mano genial

Comment: Lectura obligatoria, https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 y más aún considerando que vas por más de 400 puntos de reputación.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes utilizar lo siguiente  para detectar si tú string contiene una mayúscula, 
una minuscula o un número, esta expresion te devolverá true si lo contiene

```
bool contains = "tu string".Any(char.IsDigit) && "tu string".Any(char.IsLower) && "tu string".Any(char.IsUpper);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias me ha funcionado